# Load Oracle table from sqlloader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a huge number of `.csv` files with same columns, I need to upload the files to a table in Oracle express edition.

The Columns are as follows, I have done a sample control file. Please help me in developing the control file for this.

```
load data
INFILE 'Trade_File_3.01.2018.csv'
INTO TABLE Daily_Trades_Full
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(TRADE_DAT,
TRANSACTION_NO,
COMPANY,
MAIN_TYPE,
SUB_TYPE,
PRICE,
QUANTITY,
LOT_TYPE,
BROKER_ID_BUY,
CL_PREFIX_BUY,
CL_SUFIX_BUY,
CL_JOINT_AC_NO_BUY,
BROKER_ID_SELL,
CL_PREFIX_SELL,
CL_SUFIX_SELL,
CL_JOINT_AC_NO_SELL,
BUY_OFFICE_CODE_BRANCH,
SELL_OFFICE_CODE_BRANCH_CODE,
FORIEGN_FLAG_BUY,
FORIEGN_FLAG_SELL,
TRADE_TIME,
SOURCEID_BUY,
SOURCEID_SELL )
```

Table Structure

```
Name                         Null Type          
---------------------------- ---- ------------- 
TRADE_DAT                         VARCHAR2(9)   
TRANSACTION_NO                    VARCHAR2(20)  
COMPANY                           VARCHAR2(40)  
MAIN_TYPE                         VARCHAR2(10)  
SUB_TYPE                          VARCHAR2(10)  
PRICE                             VARCHAR2(50)  
QUANTITY                          VARCHAR2(50)  
LOT_TYPE                          VARCHAR2(10)  
BROKER_ID_BUY                     VARCHAR2(30)  
CL_PREFIX_BUY                     VARCHAR2(90)  
CL_SUFIX_BUY                      VARCHAR2(20)  
CL_JOINT_AC_NO_BUY                VARCHAR2(10)  
BROKER_ID_SELL                    VARCHAR2(30)  
CL_PREFIX_SELL                    VARCHAR2(90)  
CL_SUFIX_SELL                     VARCHAR2(20)  
CL_JOINT_AC_NO_SELL               VARCHAR2(10)  
BUY_OFFICE_CODE_BRANCH            VARCHAR2(120) 
SELL_OFFICE_CODE_BRANCH_CODE      VARCHAR2(120) 
FORIEGN_FLAG_BUY                  VARCHAR2(10)  
FORIEGN_FLAG_SELL                 VARCHAR2(10)  
TRADE_TIME                        VARCHAR2(100) 
SOURCEID_BUY                      VARCHAR2(120) 
SOURCEID_SELL                     VARCHAR2(130)
```

sample .csv file

```
TRADE_DAT   TRANSACTION_NO  COMPANY MAIN_TYPE   SUB_TYPE    PRICE   QUANTITY    LOT_TYPE    BROKER_ID_BUY   CL_PREFIX_BUY   CL_SUFIX_BUY    CL_JOINT_AC_NO_BUY  BROKER_ID_SELL  CL_PREFIX_SELL  CL_SUFIX_SELL   CL_JOINT_AC_NO_SELL BUY_OFFICE_CODE_branch  SELL_OFFICE_CODE_branch_code    FORIEGN_FLAG_BUY    FORIEGN_FLAG_SELL   TRADE_TIME  SOURCEID_BUY    SOURCEID_SELL
02-Jan-18   1   BBH     N   0   16.9    10  N   MSB 542670398   VN  0   MSB 862490355   VN  0   CMB             CMB             0   0   9:30:04 AM  ..0 B20          
02-Jan-18   2   BIL     N   0   2.7 10  N   MSB 542670398   VN  0   MSB 473153866   VN  1   CMB             CMB             0   0   9:30:05 AM  C8593           B25
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SQL LOADER in Oracle to import CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839856/using-sql-loader-in-oracle-to-import-csv-file)

Comment: We don't have your tables, your CSV files (or, at least, sample data), so - how do you expect anyone to guess how to create that control file?

Comment: Your table uses strings to store DATE and NUMERIC information, so that is bad.

Comment: Also, what is wrong with your control file? Have you actually tried loading data with it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all as I can see from your data you should delete the header of the files which includes the names of the columns.

Furthermore, your fields are separated by space, so you should write in the control file

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
```

Finally you should include the fields' type in the control file too.